# Arithmetic Mean Linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Is a function that finds the arithmetic mean of a set of real numbers a linear function?

So is $\left(X_1 +  X_2 + \cdots +  X_n\right)/n$ linear or not?

I'm not sure because so long as the set stays the same size $n$ could be defined as a constant.

Comment: Linear function in what variable(s) ?

Comment: The function that takes $n$ real numbers and returns their arithmetic mean *is* linear in $n$ variables. A "function" that takes an arbitrary finite multiset of real numbers and returns their arithmetic mean is not linear.

Comment: To rephrase: $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=(1/n)(x_1+\cdots+x_n)$ is linear; $f(n; x_1,x_2,\dots)=(1/n)(x_1+\cdots+x_n)$ is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To talk about linearity, the domain and range of a function must be vector spaces, in this case over the real numbers. So your first question should be, what vector space do you take the arithmetic mean to be defined on? It turns out you *must* fix the value of $n$ to get any reasonable vector space with the arithmetic mean defined. If you mix various length sequences, they cannot be added (and extending the shorter sequence by zeros in order to perform the addition is not an option, because this *changes* its mean value). Once you realise $n$ must be fixed, you should have no difficulty seeing that the arithmetic mean is a linear function.